# How to use AVAudioPlayerNode with AVMutableComposition

Tags: core-audio, avaudiosession, avmutablecomposition, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode

The `AVAudioEngine` and related `AVAudioNode` objects seem to be quite powerful for audio processing but it's difficult to see how to automate parameter changes with them. I'm sure there must be something more effective than manually using a `Timer` to change values, as a crude example.

`AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters` includes a method `setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:toEndVolume:timeRange:` but I cannot see how I could integrate that with `AVAudioPlayerNode` (connected with AVAudioEffectNodes) and use that method to fade the volume over time. Instead, I have only seen examples of `AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters` working with `AVMutableComposition`instances and none of them include `AVAudioNode` objects.

Can anyone post or link to some code samples that combine the use of AVAudioNodes with `setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:toEndVolume:timeRange:` or explain best practices for automating parameter changes on a node over time?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

The AVAudioEngine is a real-time engine, but AVMutableComposition  seems to be a non-real-time object.  Thus incompatible.  An alternative is to build and insert your own fader real-time AUAudioUnit node..

Comment: Given, how hard it is to find an alternative other than creating my own fader audio unit this may be the best answer. It just seems like a glaring omission in the AVAudioEngine API to not be able to gradually change a parameter over time using the built in units when it almost looks supported with the `scheduleParameterBlock`, `flag_CanRamp` etc..as part of the API. Am I the only person who feels this way. Having said that I'll upvote your answer with the hope that there is a better solution out there.